# getting wrong values while reading Double from binary file in java

Tags: java, double, binaryfiles

```
RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("BOT.grd", "r");
in.seek(28);
double xll=in.readDouble();
```

The above is the code i am using to read double data which is present from 29 to 36 byte location.The value present is 500 but i am getting 2.088E-317

Comment: There's something wrong in either the code reading the file or the code writing the file. That's all we can say without more details/code/examples. Please see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: A shot in the dark: read floats instead of doubles?

Comment: Can you give more specifics about how you are reading and writing the file?  Given that you are using `RandomAccessFile`, I guess you are not using serialization.  So how are you writing and then reading the data?  How about a code snippet for each?

Comment: I had give my code above. I was unable to read double values its working fine with integer values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this file is stored in a different [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) than the one java uses. The bytes probably need to be reversed before converting to double, you could try the following code to read the value:

```
long   l = in.readLong();
double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.reverseBytes(l));
```

Here is an example that illustrates the problem:

```
double d = 500.0;

long l1 = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
long l2 = Long.reverseBytes(l1);

System.out.println(Double.longBitsToDouble(l1));
System.out.println(Double.longBitsToDouble(l2));
```

Output:

```
500.0
2.088356E-317
```

Comment: @raviteja is this still not working for you? If so, we would need some more information or examples of this file format. But as you accepted this answer, I would assume it solved your problem.